# Government Ownership vs Private Ownership

Tags: competition, productivity

In a debate concerning long term economic strategy, a representative of a left party was trying to support that privatisation and *Small Government* which minimizes its own activities is not a viable direction in a Global Economy, i.e. it will lead to a further *loss of sovereignty* in a sense that a country applies its policies mostly via the public sector, which if minimized will have insignificant impact. Then the opponent asked a simple, but intriguing question:

*"Is there an example where a government owned company<sup>1</sup> has a product that is competitive with a product of a private company?"*

After a brief research I really couldn't find such example. Is there such an example and if not, what counter argument there could be presented against the above question?

---

<sup>1. Without the trivial and most frequent example of a monopoly.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are lots. Several state-owned energy companies succeed in international competitive markets, for example.

EDF is majority-owned by the French State, and is a successful competitor in energy markets in other countries; e.g. GB electricity retail.

DONG is majority-owned by the Danish State, and is a successful competitor in energy markets in other countries; e.g. UK offshore windfarm installation.